# Receiving 504 Gateway Time-out when getting the manifest

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

When trying to upload a model to forge we are receiving a 504 gateway timeout:

```
'GET /modelderivative/v2/designdata/***/manifest HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nAuthorization: Bearer ***\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.1\r\nHost: developer.api.autodesk.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      timeout: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path:
       '/modelderivative/v2/designdata/***/manifest',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: undefined,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
      [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
   data:
    '<html>\r\n<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n' } }
```

/nodejs/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/hostReportError.js:4
setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);

What can we try to fix this? Do you need the model or other information?
Its a model with lots of geometry.

kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're experiencing a few issues and we're working on it.

**UPDATE**

Should be back to normal now.

Comment: Is the service down now? When I try to create an scene asset through https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/modelderivative/v2/arkit/job I get an empty response instead of the usual confirmation response. I'm getting 504 Gateway Time-out too when checking manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I have the last two hours "gateway Time-Out" errors just viewing models

```
GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLmVvU0dVZFVyUTZ5UTVWZm05Rk54QWc_dmVyc2lvbj0x?domain=https%3A%2F%2Fourwebsite.net 504 (Gateway Time-out)
```